# Create and update PostgreSQL view from Drupal view

Tags: views, database

Do you know about any way to automatically create and update PostgreSQL view from Drupal view? The reason is, that there are some applications, which can use DB view, but not Drupal one, such as QGIS or JasperReports.

I know, that:

- I can copy SQL command from views (module) interface, but that's not very practical, since I would need to recreate view (on DB level) on any edit.
- It's not possible to convert some Views features, such as permissions handling or any other functionality which is dependent on hooks.